# detect back navigation and tab close or browser close in angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular14

Problem: I want to know about back navigation and tab close in angular 14 after back navigated or tab closed.

What I tried: I used beforeunload event but it tells me before it is done and I tried popstate method but it don't work.I tried many other methods but they also didn't work.

```js
    @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    // Code to execute when the user navigates back or closes the tab/window
    console.log(window.performance.navigation.type);
    if (window.performance.navigation.type === 0) {
      console.log("User navigated back");
    }
    else if (window.performance.navigation.type === 2) {
      console.log("tab Closed");
    }
  }
```

I tried this but tells me before but i want to know after navigated back and tab closed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.